# Two Phases of Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol (SSTP)

Tags: tls, session-management

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol there are two phases, SSL phase and PPP phase.

SSL phase establishes a session

[image]

and PPP also creates a link (which I understand to be a session)

[image]

I am unable to find the difference between the two phases. It seems these phases are one and the same. Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first phase is to establish a secure session.  This is what the SSL session is for.  Once the SSL channel is established all data passed through it is encrypted.  The POP session is established *through* the SSL session.  Which means that all of its messages for establishing a PPP session are encrypted using the SSL encryption keys.

PPP allows for authenticating users.  So any user names, passwords, or other means of user  authentication is encrypted.   SSH does the same sort of process.  Establish a secure channel first, then allow for secure user authentication and data transfer.

Comment: that's what I thought, but wasn't 100% sure